# How to auto calculate/resolve a named cell within a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have **A1 = 5** and I've added **A1** as a name "**Protagonist**".

If i do `=Protagonist` its going to come up with **5**.

Say in D12 I want to do `=Protagonist+1` Its going to come up with **6**.

- What i want achieve is replace the "**protagonist**" with the **5**
  and have the **D12** formula remain `=5+1`.

I need to do this as **A1** constantly changes its value and I only need to keep the value it has at the time of making a formula that uses it.

(Manually i know i can select **Protagonist** and hit **F9** to resolve only that part of the formula, but thats a major time consumption in the amounts i have to do it)

This can happen after the formula is entered and resolved. Though it would be so amazing if it could happen in the formula bar while typing, but I would guess vba doesn't stretch that far.

Comment: Do you want **D12** to become:  `=A1 + 1` or `=5 + 1` or `=6` or `6` ??

Comment: It is mentioned - i want it to remain/become =5+1

Comment: Could you please explain why you want to do this? If you explain the underlying problem, someone may very well know how to resolve the problem without resorting to this kind of solution.

Comment: So every time you type a formula with a named range, you want it to instead inject the *current value* of that named range and remain static going forward?

Comment: Gary solved it. And if gave you guys the document and had you analyze it and me explain it to you it would be wasting much of your time.

Comment: @Excellll however if you just want it out of curiosity I can provide and example file for you or anyone to check.

Comment: @Raystafarian yeah. Gary's done it on a manual trigger script. I'll make do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to replace it with the calculated value then:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Count = 1 Then
    If Left(Target.Formula, 1) = "=" And IsNumeric(Intersect(Range("B1:F1000"), Target)) Then
      Dim a As Variant
      For Each a In Array("protagonist", "anotherNameToChange")
        While InStr(1, Target.Formula, a, 1)
          Target.Formula = Replace(Target.Formula, a, Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names(a).Value), , , 1)
        Wend
      Next
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Will do it for all names in array also automatically as desired...

If there is need to do it for every name change the followimg 2 lines:

```
For Each a In Array("protagonist", "anotherNameToChange")
```

changes to:

```
For Each a In ThisWorkbook.Names
```

and

```
Target.Formula = Replace(Target.Formula, a, Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names(a).Value), , , 1)
```

to

```
Target.Formula = Replace(Target.Formula, a, Evaluate(a.Value), , , 1)
```

Just note that this is not case sensitive :)

Comment: Yeah, i use a ton of other names, doing it for everything is going to stab me. Hence the oddly named protagonist - that has no chance of appearing on my document in any form of text.

Comment: as long as it is working like expected everything is fine... if you need any adjustements, just tell me... i'll add a second way... just a sec...

Comment: Yeah i only need it done for protagonist. not every name. And you can bind it to a range A1 to C1000 if you don't mind. Doesn't need to scour the whole document looking for it.

Comment: @helena4 changed it... just put all names to replace in the array (also works with just 1 item)

Comment: Cool, feel free to bump up gary's answer, he put sweat into it too :) We are done.

Comment: as i do it allways :)

Comment: Can i trouble you for an option to limit it to a range say, B1 to F1000?

Comment: edited my answer to show how you can add it :)

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
Sub qwerty()
   Dim N As Name, FixString As String

   Set N = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Protagonist")
   FixString = N.RefersToRange

   For Each cell In Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
      cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "Protagonist", FixString)
   Next cell
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To call `qwerty` from an *Event Macro*, use something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C100")) Is nothen Then
   Else
      Application.EnableEvents = False
         Call qwerty
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you think it would be much of a performance drag if this is bound searching 3 columns 1000 rows and performing the replacement on cells found at the time a standard recalc triggers or me pressing enter? Otherwise i don't mind binding it to a button - Just asking.

Comment: @helena4  You can always restrict it by using something like: `Range("A1:C1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`

Comment: As far I grasp (and its not large knowledge base) this is only manually run. Can you bind it to a worksheet change and call it a day? And btw how much time does this vba stuff take to learn. I might lean on my boss to send me to a course so i can stop bothering you guys here with odd requests every now and then :)

Comment: @helena4  Sure.....create an event macro and then have the Event macro call **qwerty**.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, this isn't possible.

I suspect the answer, if one exists at all, is to understand the reasoning (the business logic) behind you wanting this behaviour, then reformatting the workbook to suit.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical - I've used vba to replace stuff in cells before, just not parts of the whole. The name getting replaced after the formula is entered should be sufficient, even if it can't happen in the formula bar. If vba is a dead end this is solve-able with peripherals. I just need to buy a mouse that can bind macros to extra keys and paste ="="&Protagonist then hit 9 and continue onward. As for the logic can't fit a brief in here. Suffice to say i have to refer to a dynamic match in a ever growing entry list. And I haven't been able to simplify the goal/means any more.

Comment: If you want to retrospectively change the cell value (protagonist+1) to its source value (5+1) then sure, that's simple and can even happen automatically with a `WorksheetChange` event, but that's not what I took from the question.

Comment: Yes I clarified it to avoid any further interpretation. It simply meant I'd prefer it happen in the formula bar, but its cool it took place after the formula is entered.